# Responsiveness option disabled in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm studying Power BI and I want to make the graphics responsive, but they all have the "Responsive" option turned off and disabled as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTcQz.png). How can I enable this option? The components in question are a table and a filter. I'm using the latest version of Power BI, I downloaded it last week.

All tutorials I found show this option enabled. [On the Power BI forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1180056/how-can-i-enable-greyed-out-responsive-button-in-g), I found other people with the same problem, but no one responded there. I imagine that here at StackOverFlow there are more active and knowledgeable people to respond.

Answer (score 0):

The Responsive option is only enabled when it is relevant/supported.
For Table and Matrix visuals, it isn't supported.
For Slicer - it is enabled only if you change the Slicer settings Style to Tile (and for date/number slicers, for Between, Before, After).
[image]